# Why is my action bar opening at the bottom, as opposed to the top?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I have followed a tutorial which shows you how to create a simple action bar at the top of the page, but when I complete it and open the action bar; it opens at the bottom like an options menu, as opposed to being at the top? Whereas I want it to open at the top like in the tutorial:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/

Any advice will be helpful:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<

menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/whitecog"
          android:title="@string/title"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:showAsAction="never" />
     <!-- Check updates -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_check_updates"
          android:icon="@drawable/whitecog"
          android:title="@string/action_check_updates"
          android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Java:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

Thanks,

Callum

Upon request here is the manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.application"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.application.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.application.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.application.ShowTeamsChosen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_show_teams_chosen" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Also I am running off 4.4.2

Comment: Can you add your Android Manifest? [Edit] it into the post. Also, what version of Android are you running and compiling under?

Comment: Do you have a device with a physical menu button?

Comment: I have added the manifest, and am working off android 4.4.2. Also I do have a device with a physical menu button yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a physical menu button it is completely normal that the overflow menu opens at the bottom. 
All devices with physical menu button - today it is mostly Samsung devices - do not have the overflow menu at the top right. This was default before Honeycomb, but it has been deprecated since then. There are only a few OEM that still resist this notion - like Samsung which I already mentioned.

For those devices that still have them the `ActionBar` will default back to the old behaviour and will not display the new hamburger overflow menu.

Comment: Ah ok I see, so how would I get it to appear at the top right? If there is any way.

Comment: There is not way and you shouldn't attempt it anyway. People how use a phone with menu button are accustomed to using the menu button. If your app would ignore this it would just confuse your users. Just don't worry about it. Devices without menu button will have the hamburger overflow menu in the `ActionBar` and devices with menu button will have it open at the bottom. This is desired behaviour.

Comment: Ah I see, so it depends on which device you have. This has cleared it all up for me now, thanks +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

To make it stay at the top of the screen, remove

```
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow
```

From your activity definition in your manifest file.